# SoapUI Assertions Failing to Detect Decimal

Tags: xml, soap, soapui, assertions

I am attempting to validate an XML response in SoapUI.

The response field in question looks exactly like this:

```
<amount>5225.00</amount>
```

I created an assertion to verify the amount as 5225.00 but am getting the error:

```
"Expecting [5225.00], actual was [5225]"
```

Because the amount field is supposed to return a dollar amount I do want to verify cents are included even when 0. The response is returning "5225.00". Why is SoapUI not correctly identifying this?

Using XPath Match:

```
Declare: 
#Response#\\*\*amount[1]
Expected Result: 
5225.00
```

Exact Response XML:

```
<amount>5225.00</amount>
```

The assertion retunrs true if I change the expected result to 5225 (no decimals).

Comment: Can you please add the details? What kind of assertion you were trying to do? Are you using any properties while doing this?

Comment: Xpath match returns true when I remove .00 from expected result. But I need to checked that the result carries 2 decimal places..

Comment: Using a sample xml with a amount field I give back de decimals in the xpath and the assertion works ok. Furthermore your xpath is an invalid xpath expression `\\*\*amount[1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate the xml Response from the SoapUI

We can validate response using xpath like xpath/text()

use the function text(), text() will convert the your xpath value to String and then you can validate against this with 5225.00